# Angular2 [selected] issue with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, select, angular, html-select, selected

**myValues**

```
{
    "level": [
        {
            "name": "Zero Level",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "First Level",
            "value": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

**Select Box**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="form.cache.level" name="level" required>
    <option
        *ngFor="let levelof myValues.level"
        [selected] ="level.value === 0"
        [value]="level.value">
        {{ level.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

despite of fact, that the level.value === 0 is true, it won't be selected in Chrome. (Firefox and IE work)

As workaround I initialize:

```
form.cache.level = 0
```

But I would like to know, why does it not work with Chrome? (Here is a [playground](https://plnkr.co/edit/gmcHr2GLom4ibZf4pWDw?p=preview) for further analysis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ngModel` overrides the behavior of the `selected` attribute, so if you choose the model you always should set the bound value instead of trying to modify the selection with option attributes.

It's probably working accidentally in Firefox/IE.